# How do I prevent Pi prompt for username and password ?

Tags: raspbian, pi-3, pi-2, linux, retropie

I have an arcade run on raspberry pi 3 flashed with RetroPie 4.4.

Just now, I'm not sure what had happened to my Pi hardware, network, or even SD card when I boot, I kept getting prompt to enter the `username` and `password`.

[image]

**How do I stop that ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming your using the default username and password.

From the command line enter 'sudo raspi-config'

Select 'Boot Options', 'Desktop/CLI', 'Console Autologin'

[image]

Comment: Cool. Let me try that right now.

Comment: It seems to work on the first shot. Thanks for your help !